# Show post taxonomy information in custom page template in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a theme i am editing through a child theme. I have been able to create a custom page template because i want to add the taxonomy information for a specific post type using the custom page.

The custom page has the following code

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area col-sm-12 col-md-8 <?php echo of_get_option( 'site_layout' ); ?>">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

I need to add the taxonomy information below each description. Say the name of post type is foods how do i add code to the above to also show the taxonomy (created, size, time, type) information for each post.

Answer (score 1):

add below code in while loop for category list as per the post id.

```
//Returns Array of Term for "my_taxonomy"
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'my_taxonomy' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 

    $terms_links = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $terms_links[] = $term->name;
    }

    $on_terms = join( ", ", $terms_links );
    ?>

    <p>
        <?php printf( esc_html__( 'Categories : <span>%s</span>', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $on_terms ) ); ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ok will try it and revert